# With pyodbc & SQL Server, how to insert foreign keys

Tags: python, sql-server, foreign-keys, pyodbc

I have two tables, Region(**ID**, province, country), and Address(address1, address2, city, **RegionID**). Using pyodbc, I first inserted my Region table without any issues. I am now trying to figure out how to insert the FK_RegionID during the insertion of my Address table.

Here is functional code, without any mention of inserting the RegionID (the intersect part is to not allow the insertion of duplicate rows):

```
cursor.execute((""" 
    IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT @address1, @address2, @city
        INTERSECT
        SELECT address1, address2, city
        FROM dbo.Address)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Address (address1, address2, city)
        VALUES (@address1, @address2, @city)
    END""")
```

Ideally, I would add a query to my insert, such as `(SELECT RegionID FROM dbo.Region WHERE province=@province AND country=@country)`. However, that doesn't work.

```
    ...
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Address (address1, address2, city, RegionID)
        VALUES (@address1, @address2, @city, SELECT...WHERE...)
    END""")
```

I also saw that one could use `fetchall()`, but I'm not sure how to go about it, and how much longer it would make the insert of the Address table. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select may not work in a VALUES clause, but you could add the values to a SELECT list, like this:

```
...
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Address (address1, address2, city, RegionID)
    SELECT @address1, @address2, @city, RegionID 
    FROM dbo.Region
    WHERE province=@province AND country=@country)
END""")
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, because `@address1, @address2, @city` are not `FROM dbo.Region` though..
Also, does an INSERT INTO() not require a VALUES() ?

Comment: @CharlesLeblanc No it does not. You can do `INSERT...SELECT...` this is especially useful when inserting multiple rows directly from another table. This particular form doesn't work if there is no matching row in `Region`

Comment: I tried it, and it indeed works, thanks to the both of you!

Answer (score 1):

As well as the version given in the other answer, you could use a scalar subquery or an `OUTER APPLY`, both of which will just return `NULL` if there is no row.

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.Address (address1, address2, city, RegionID)
    VALUES (@address1, @address2, @city, (SELECT RegionID FROM dbo.Region WHERE province=@province AND country=@country) );

INSERT INTO dbo.Address (address1, address2, city, RegionID)
    SELECT v.address1, v.address2, v.city, r.RegionID
    FROM (VALUES(@address1, @address2, @city)) AS v(address1, address2, city)
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT RegionID
        FROM dbo.Region
        WHERE province=@province AND country=@country
    ) r;
```